# Distinguish row clicks in Antd (ant design) table React component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design table component: https://ant.design/components/table/#Table

In each row, I'm rendering a title and some link. For example:

```
Product 1
https://example.com/link/product/1
```

I'm using the `onRow` API to open a modal to edit the info for the row, which is working fine. However, the `onRow` event is also trigged if I click on the link. Is there a way to not trigger the `onRow` event if I just click on the link in the row, and still keep everything as normal if I click on anywhere on the row cell?

Note: my current work around is using an `isEditing` state flag, but it's not a good experience since I have to get into "edit mode" and set `isEditing` to true.

Answer (score 24):

You'd better show your code usage of `onRow` and `columns`, If you use `onRow.onClick` like below:

```
<Table
  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onClick: event => {}, // click row
    };
  }}
/>
```

You can custom render of link with [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) like this:

```
const columns = [
  {
    dataIndex: "link",
    title: "Link",
    render: (value) => {
      return (
        <a
          onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
          href={value}
          target="_blank"
        >
          Link
        </a>
      );
    }
  }
]
```